# .replace in eval with dynamic variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, dynamic, eval, laravel-5

I've been trying to fix this for hours now and just can't get it to work. I'm retrieving the name of every activity in the database and for every row it recreates this script with the correct data.

```
<script>var count = 1;</script>
    @foreach($data as $scriptdata)
        <script>

            eval("var id" + count + " = '{{$scriptdata->activiteit}}';");
            eval("var clas" + count + " = '{{$scriptdata->activiteit}}';");
            eval("var id" + count + " = id" + count .replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '') + ";");
            eval("var clas" + count + " = clas" + count .replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '') + ";");



            $("#" + id1).mouseenter(function(event) {
                console.log("clicked.");

                var target = $('.' + clas1);

                if( target.length ) {
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top-120
                    }, 1000);
                }

            });
            count++

        </script>
        @endforeach
```

the variables become dynamic without any trouble, I just can't get that .replace to do it's job.

anyone?:p

Comment: Use an object with bracket notation. Or change it so the scope is not using global variables so it does not matter at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either output the variables from the serverside code, use Objects with bracket notation, use common classes so there is no need to have individual selections, or make it so the variables are not in global scope.

Make it so the variable are not in global scope

```
(function() {
  var id = '{{$scriptdata->activiteit}}';
  var clas = '{{$scriptdata->activiteit}}';

  $("#" + id).mouseenter(function(event) {

    var target = $('.' + clas);

    if (target.length) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top - 120
      }, 1000);
    }

  });
}());
```

Now you do not have to worry about count.